# How Could I Add Image Upload Option To The Registration Form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

My forms.py is this.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm,UserChangeForm

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email= forms.EmailField(required = True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'
        }

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()
```

And, i have to add "upload image" option for the user so that user could upload their image from any file and load it on the profile.

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend your user model with field `profile_image = models.FileField()` [there is tutorial how to do it](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html).

Than you have to add

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email= forms.EmailField(required = True)
    profile_image = forms.FileField() # add this field

    ...

    def save(self, commit=True):
        ...
        user.profile_image = self.cleaned_data.get('profile_image')
        ...
```

and add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to the `<form ...>` tag in the html template. Here is tutorial from Django docs on [File Uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/).

**EDIT**

Extending the User model in the most basic way without changing the actual User model is that you'll create new model with one-to-one relation to the user model.

```
from django.conf import settings

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    profile_image = models.FileField() # where is stored the user profile image
```

this is the Profile of each user. You will have to create profile when user is created, so:

place this code to the any `models.py` or file that is loaded on the startup with django

```
from django.contrib import auth
auth.models.User.add_to_class('create_profile', create_profile)
```

then create the method below

```
from (appname).models import Profile

def create_profile(self, **kwargs):
    Profile.objects.create(
        user=self,
        **kwargs # you can pass other fields values upon creating
    )
```

then modify to the `RegistrationForm` as I wrote before and modify the save function

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

    # user has to be saved to add profile
    user.save()
    user.create_profile() 
    user.profile_img = self.cleaned_data.get('profile_image')
    user.profile.save()

    if commit:
        user.save()
```

also when you are instantiating the RegistrationForm with request.POST do it like

```
form = RegistrationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
# to the files have to be passed also, they are not in request.POST
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

and thats it.

Comment: Can u help me with complete procedure of extending user model with field profile_image = models.FileField() I can't get those tutorials

Comment: I'll update my answer, check it out some minutes later.